# Hibernate no consulta ultimo registro en base de datos

Tags: java, hibernate, select

Un batch esta tratando de consultar un registro de la base de datos para posteriormente actualizarlo, pero simultáneamente el usuario modifica ese mismo registro y alcanza a hacer commit, dado que el batch ya se estaba ejecutando consulta y obtiene el registro antiguo (cache de primer nivel) y sobrescribe lo que el usuario actualizo.

Como puedo hacer para que en la consulta del batch force a buscar en la base de datos?

Consulta que realiza el batch:

```
ChildLineDTO result = childLineDAO.find(entityId);
```

Metodo find:

```
K entityFind  = (K) getHibernateTemplate().get(class1, entityId);
```

Comment: A que te refieres con batch?

Comment: Tienes dos aplicaciones distintas accediendo a la base de datos? En ese caso tendrás que desactivar la cache de al menos una de ellas (si el batch no escribe en base de datos, puedes mantener activa la caché de la primera aplicación)

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solución a mi problema, funciono creando una nueva sesión y realizando la consulta.

```
Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        K entityFind = (K) session.get(class1, entityId);
```